# How do I compare the return of `which`  with -1 in a script?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to set a script that finds the location of bash then uses it in the shabang, I'm not using `env` because the example script I read said to use a symbolic link to `env` in case it's not in `usr/bin` so why do that when I can just use `which` to find `bash` then set a link to it?
The problem I'm having is comparing the return of `which` if the command isn't found ( -1)
***Edit: I read the manual wrong `which` only returns -1 if no agrs are sent to it***

but -1 is a newline and when I compare it is true I get the error that I'm comparing a string `/bin/bash` to a number -1

I've tried a few different ways but can't figure out how to get it to work

```
newname=$(which bash)
echo $newname
fault=-1
if [ "$newname" = fault ] ; then
echo couldn\'t find bash shell
else
#! newname
```

Comment: What you are trying to do (set a shebang late) is not possible.  A shebang is only a shebang if `#!` are the first two characters in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to set a script that finds the location of bash then uses
>   it in the shabang

You can't do that.  What's happening now is your script is being run by the shell by default anyway.  If it weren't, how could you use the shell to get the location of the shell in a script?  Even if you rename it "script.blah" and remove any shebang, as long as it is executable and contains shell commands, the shell will run it.

If you place a shebang halfway down the page, it won't mean anything -- it will just be a comment.  For a shebang to be shebang, `#!` needs to be **the first two characters in the file**.  This is to tell the shell to pass off to whatever; if it doesn't find that, it assumes it is a shell script anyway.  If you want to invoke some other shell or interpreter after that, you have to do it the same way you would on the command line.

Comment: And I should be checking what shell i'm running first

Comment: If you do use a shebang and the shell you ask for is available, that's what will be used, and if not, the execution will probably bail. `/usr/bin/bash` is very standard.  It's not your responsibility to worry about people who have their system configured in some non-standard way.  Generally, `$SHELL` will be set to the path to the default shell, which is what will be running your script if you didn't use a shebang.  Beyond that, I'm not sure if there is a way to determine who's doing the executing.

Answer (score 2):

Not only is there absolutely no reason to do what you're doing, trying to detect the location of the shell assumes the script is already running in a shell.

Whatever you read about `env` is wrong. There's no reason to expect it to be a symlink. People use `env` in a shebang because there's a slightly greater chance of finding `env` under `/usr/bin` than of finding `Bash` under `/bin`, but many people don't even bother with that. Presumably the reason you're jumping through hoops like this is for the sake of portability, in which case `which` is a very bad and nonstandard choice. Instead, use `type`, or in ksh, `whence`. For example:

```
if x=$(type -p bash); then
    "$x" myscript
else
    echo "Not found" >&2
fi
```

Unfortunately what `type` does exactly isn't even very well standardized either. Just execute the commands, and the shell will either do its thing or throw an error. Checking for the existence of a command is only necessary in uncommon situations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$?` to reference the return value of the last run process. For example:

```
name=$(which bash)
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; 
    then echo "found"; 
fi
```

#### Note

In your question you seem to assume that an error is always -1. In general this isn't true. A program will return a non-zero error code to the shell. Therefore 0 is success and any other value (including -1) is a failure.

Comment: I've already tryed that but thanks for the error comment I read the which manual wrong

Comment: @UNECS: Your question is a bit odd. The title asks 'how to compare the return value of which..'. I interpreted this as the return value of the process 'which'. This is what I answered. What did you try? The example I posted worked....

Comment: $? shouldn't be used there. `if` takes a command, and an assignment statement is a command. See my answer.

Comment: @ormaaj: the [[ ... ]] construct is called the extended test command (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS).

Comment: @sashang It's called the "conditional expression compound command". For performing numerical comparisons, the arithmetic compound command should be preferred: `(($? == 0))`, however, testing $? shouldn't be done at all if the exit status can be tested directly (like it can here). Also, ABS isn't a good source of information. It's packed with errors and bad advice.

Comment: @ormaaj: ok I give up. I like your method better anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You could run

```
which bash && found=true
```

Found will only be set on a successful termination of which (that is, if it is found)

Comment: I tryed that out of interest even tho its been shown what i'm doing doesn't work and which only returns -1 if no args are sent to it.